audio issue with Apogee Symphony, Apple Studio M1 Max
I apologize beforehand for the really long question...
Here's my hardware:

Apple Studio M1 Max (OS 12.3.1 64GB ram) in Native Silicon mode;
Apogee Symphony MK1 i/o (SN: A6M010130300100), with an 8x8 AES card, a 16-out card, in addition to the original 2x6 card;
ThunderBridge v1.50

I record in both Pro Tools 2023.6.0 and Logic 10.7.4. I've used the Symphony for ~10 years, and it has always sounded beautiful. However in recent weeks the input-monitored and recorded sound is hard and harsh - like jitter or maybe a Word Clock thing - hard transients, especially on high notes (tho electric bass sounds fine). Colleagues hear it too.
I've checked the whole analog chain - instruments, microphones, preamps, etc., into an analog monitor controller; everything sounds as good as always ... so I've ruled out anything analog being the cause.
I've tried:

using an external Word Clock generator;
both USB Mode, and using the ThunderBridge;
switched out Symphony modules;
borrowed a friend's Symphony MK1;
tested recording and input-monitoring in both Pro Tools and Logic;
my old Intel Mac Pro with Symphony 64 PCIE and Pro Tools 12;

... all with the same result.
I've tried the Symphony's 'standalone' mode, monitoring the Symphony's headphone output - and it sounded good!
Like I said, until a few weeks ago it sounded beautiful. I can't think of anything else to try.
I suspect that something is either conflicting or corrupted in the communication between the Symphony MK1 and Maestro 2 version 2.11.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem before?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.
svs
